# Encrypt the data before store in local storage in Redux offline npm package

Tags: encryption, react-redux, redux-persist, redux-offline

In my react application I'm using [Redux Offline](https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline) for offline features for persist the application data when offline. This package store data in browser local storage. I need to encrypt the data when storing to local storage. I got to know [redux-persist-transform-encrypt](https://github.com/maxdeviant/redux-persist-transform-encrypt) is capable of this and it is work with [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) and this encryption can be implemented, but this encryption package in not directly work with Redux Offline but under the hood Redux Offline also build on top of redux-persist. Is it possible to config Redux Offline with redux-persist-transform-encrypt or any other possible approach for this?.